# Radiobuttons in XML / XSL

Tags: xml, forms, xslt

First: Sorry, my english is not the best, but I try to write as good as possible.

My Path in `.XML` file:

```
<ClinicalDocument>
<recordTarget>
<patientRole>
<rezeptgebuehrenbefreiung>ja</rezeptgebuehrenbefreiung>
```

If in `.XML` file in

```
<rezeptgebuehrenbefreiung>
```

is a **yes**, then the result should be:

> **yes (radiobutton=checked) (radiobutton) no**

If in `.XML` in

```
<rezeptgebuehrenbefreiung>
```

is a **no**, then the result should be:

> **yes (radiobutton) (radiobutton=checked) no**

In my `.XSL` file it looks like this as far:

```
...
<xsl:variable name="rezeptgebbefr"> 
<xsl:choose>

<xsl:when test="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:rezeptgebuehrenbefreiung">

<xsl:value-of select="/n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:recordTarget/n1:patientRole/n1:rezeptgebuehrenbefreiung"/>

</xsl:when>

<xsl:otherwise>unspecified</xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>

</xsl:variable>
...
```

I don't know how I get the `radiobutton`s to the correct place. I tried different solutions of Google, but they also don't work.

Maybe somebody can help me!
Thank you very much!

Greetings,
Mario

Comment: Please check your question. The requested output (text?!) does not seem to be reasonable.

Comment: There should be two radiobuttons. One is checked, the other is NOT checked. Before the first button should be "yes" and after the second should be "no". The Problem is how I get here the correct radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a named template where you can create the radio button, with parameters for the name of the buttons, the value, and what the currently selected value is:

```
<xsl:template name="radiobutton">
    <xsl:param name="name" />
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:param name="currentvalue" />

    <input type="radio" name="{$name}" value="{$value}">
        <xsl:if test="$value = $currentvalue">
            <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </input>
    <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
    <br />
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can output the two buttons; one for 'yes' and one for 'no', like so:

```
    <xsl:variable name="rezeptgebbefr" select="n1:rezeptgebuehrenbefreiung" />

    <xsl:call-template name="radiobutton">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'test'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'yes'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="currentvalue" select="$rezeptgebbefr" />
    </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:call-template name="radiobutton">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'test'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'no'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="currentvalue" select="$rezeptgebbefr" />
    </xsl:call-template>
```